# JQuery Mobile 1.4.2 selectmenu().selectmenu('refresh') not working properly

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, select-menu, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I have tried using the 2 codes below to refresh the selectmenu, but they didn't work.

```
$('#gender').selectmenu('refresh'); // not working
$('#gender').selectmenu('refresh',true); // not working
```

---

These 3 codes working, but the layout duplicated.

```
$('#gender').selectmenu(); 
$('#gender').selectmenu().selectmenu('refresh');
$('#gender').selectmenu().selectmenu('refresh', true);
```

original selectmenu:

[image: original image]

after adding either one of the 3 codes above, it become:

[image]

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What are trying to do? It would be helpful if you can create a jsfiddle demo to show the issue you're having. Screenshots are quite helpful but they can only go so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are trying to apply the styling for second time which it causes problem.

To avoid that, add `data-role="none"` to your select element.

It should look something like this:

```
<select name="gender" id="gender" data-role="none">
    <option value="0">female</option>
    <option value="1">male</option>
</select>
```

Then, when you ready to apply styling, just apply it for once:

```
$('#gender').selectmenu();
```

This way, you shouldn't have duplicate layout problem.